# Loading platform-specific dependencies

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I cannot figure out how to make bundler to install platform-dependent gems.

As recommended in [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/man/gemfile.5.html) I use `:platforms` option in the Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
gem "pry-byebug", platforms: [:mri_20, :mri_21]
gem "pry-debugger", platforms: :mri_19
```

And I don't include the dependencies to `my_gem.gemspec`, 'cause it doesn't provide tools for platform-dependent specification.

When I run `bundle` all is OK: the corresponding gem is included to the `Gemfile.lock` as expected.

**The problem** arises when I use my gem in another ("host") gem.

When I run `bundle` in the host gem root, the platform-specific dependencies are skipped and missing in the `host_gem/Gemfile.lock`.

It seems like Bundler installs only dependencies specified in the gemspec, not in the Gemfile.

So my question is **how to properly define platform-specific dependencies to be loaded by depending gems**?

Comment: I've seen that post, but it tells nothing about the subject above

Comment: D'oh! It was so obvious.

I does all that things and then... forgotten to add dependencies to gemspec.

Thanks a lot!